nslookup 10.10.7.180 ** server can't find 180.7.10.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN | Ubutu DNS issue
I have tested all files like forward.zone/reverse.zone and named.conf.option/local. All looks good, but I am still not getting a reverse nslookup.
nslookup 10.11.2.180
** server can't find 180.7.10.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN


you need to provide more context/details to maximise the chance of getting a useful answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

The 10.x.x.x is a private address block, not routeable. What are you expecting?
